Conical raster shape on Point array - QGIS
I'm trying to replicate the attached shape as a DEM raster, by generating a revolved spline about each point of an array. The points will all have varying elevation and ideally I'd like the root diameter of the cones to be 2x the height. Just having trouble finding the right tool for this.



Don't know how to pythonize it in QGIS, but will show an example in R.
Let's create basic raster, which will be used for calculation: dimensions: 100x100, values = NA (empty), crs doesn't matter as long as it's metric.
r <- terra::rast(nrows = 100, ncols = 100, nlyrs = 1, xmin = 0, xmax = 10, ymin = 0, ymax = 10, vals = NA, crs = "EPSG:2180")

Let's add a points with arbitrary value = 1 (imagine it's coordinates corresponds to your desired highest points) and visualize it:
x <- 42
y <- c(31, 77)
r[x, y] <- 1
terra::plot(r)


As your bell shaped curve is rotational symmetric, we have to calculate distance in each and every direction (and using the fact that raster is finite, we have to calculate distance between each raster cell and our starting points). This distance will be used to calculate the Z value of the curve. Using terra::distance() function - it's creates the raster with cell values == distance to nearest non-NA cell.

s <- terra::distance(r)
terra::plot(s)


And now apply a function and calculate the values based on distance. In below example that's Bessel function of 0-order, but you can modify it with your curve.
terra::values(r) <- besselJ(s[,], 0)
terra::plot(r)


lidR::plot_dtm3d(r)


Created on 2024-04-08 with reprex v2.1.0
